# Handling form input with JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple form with mostly text inputs. I want when the user click on a button, he can review his form inputs.

for example, suppose we have the following form:

```
Name: [text-input-type]
Address: [text-input-type]
Phone-number: [text-input-type]

[submit button]
```

When I click on submit, I want to see the input that I entered in other place of the page (say, in other div). It looks like that:

```
Name: John Doe
Address: My USA Address
Phone-number: +201-3030-15
```

How can I do that without writing the entire form field again in my HTML using JQuery/ JS?

Comment: what have you tired??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the fields of a form are treated as a single array, you can do a loop that looks for all the inputs with type text within the form and append its values to a string. Please take a look at the demo in the fiddle.

```
var form = document.querySelector("#magic");
var info = document.querySelector("#info");
var content = "";

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        if (form[i].type === "text") {
            content += form[i].id + ": " + form[i].value + "<br>";
        }
    }

    info.innerHTML = content;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2tdwk8y/2/

Comment: Wow!! thank you so much!! Appreciate your efforts :)
It works excellent!

Comment: By the way: If I want to replace the submit button with a regular button which located outside the form, it is possible? In other words: when I click on other button (instead of submit) I want that the form fields will appear in their place (as before). What should I write here instead of submit?
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can dispatch an event manually when the user clicks on the button external to the form. You can create a new event object and pass it the event type to the constructor. http://jsfiddle.net/g2tdwk8y/5/. Note: the CustomEvent constructor is not supported in IE. You can use a polyfill to support IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent.CustomEvent

Answer (score 0):

You may stop the default action to prevent form submit and get values in this form to build what you need in another place.
`e.preventDefault();`